# why is $h(z)=\int_{[a,z]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw$ holomorphic?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ open, convex, $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic and $f(z)\ne 0$ for all $z\in U$. Let $a\in U$. How to prove (with the definition)  that $h:U\to \mathbb{C}$

$$h(z)=\int_{[a,z]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw$$is holomorphic? Here $[a,z]$ means that we have a line integral from $a$ to $z$. I start with: Let $z_0\in U$ then $$\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{h(z)-h(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{\int_{[a,z]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw-\int_{[a,z_0]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw}{z-z_0}.$$ I'm not sure how to continue. I can go directly from $a$ to $z_0$ but im not sure if follows $\int_{[a,z]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw-\int_{[a,z_0]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw=\int_{[z,z_0]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw$ and what to do next.

Edit: other ways to prove that the function is holomorphic are welcome too! Maybe it's easier with morera, that $\int_{\gamma}h(y)dy=0$ for every closed curve $\gamma$ which parametrizes a triangle. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: $h(z)=\int_{[a,z]}\frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw=\int_{[a,z]}\frac{d(f(w))}{f(w)}=\int_{[a,z]}d(\log f(w))$